# Installing Apache 2.2 with PHP7.x on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, apache, legacy

For support of legacy software based on Coldfusion 10 I need to setup Apache 2.2. I would rather move on from Ubuntu 12.04 for this. I spent some time building Apache 2.2 from source and then did the same with PHP 7.1. Unfortunately, getting them to work together was just too tricky - I couldn't find out how to generate mod_php7.1.

I've looked quite hard for guides for this online, but they're generally a bit bitty, and haven't given me any joy. I suspect I've not been searching smart enough.

Any ideas? Other than "don't use Apache 2.2!"

Comment: Not sure what [instructions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php) you followed or what problem you faced. In any case... Do you need to run Coldfusion and PHP on the same Apache instance? Do you need to run PHP as Apache module?

Comment: You should ask this on [Ask Ubuntu](//askubuntu.com)

Comment: I do want to run them on the same instance. I don't necessarily have to run PHP as an Apache module, I just thought that was a good way to do it.

Comment: ...and in terms of what instructions, well, bits and bobs from here and there (which is kind of why I was asking. I guess I could cobble together the steps I took). Essentially download and extract source, run a configure script and make/make install. I was assuming that it's the PHP compilation job to make an apache module. I was hoping that providing the "--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs" bit would encourage the compiler to generate a mod_phpxx.so file, but it didn't (and it took AGES to compile!).

Comment: ask ubuntu sounds like a good call, thanks.

Comment: I can't tell you how to build PHP from sources (I've never done it myself) but you may get further if you start with the official instructions and ask about the specific issues you encounter. But if you don't really need mod_php on Apache 2.2 you may just want to either run PHP as CGI on Apache 2.2 or simply run mod_php in an Apache 2.4 instance (your system package manager possibly has a ready to use setup), using a different IP + port combination.

Comment: Good thought. I did try the "official way" (https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php) but had much the same problem, "LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so" was no good because modules/libphp7.so wasn't there (or anywhere!).